# Handling Failed Mails in Laravel Fortify: Logging Error 500 Only

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-fortify

In my Laravel Fortify application, I am facing issues with handling failed mail sending. Specifically, when an attempt to send an email fails, it triggers an error 500 response, which is not desirable from a user experience perspective.

I want to improve the handling of email sending failures to prevent error 500 responses. Instead, I aim to gracefully handle these errors and log them for further investigation. My objective is to show a user-friendly message indicating that the email could not be sent, without revealing specific error details to the user.

To achieve this, I need to implement a solution that allows the application to continue with the user registration or other processes even if email sending encounters an issue. I want to log any errors related to email sending, while the application keeps functioning smoothly and displays meaningful feedback to users regarding email verification or other email-related functionalities.

I'm using Fortify to handle the authentication.

Adding a try catch inside Fortify actions, expected it to catch the mail error but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Fortify, handling failed mails can be done using the built-in notification system provided by Laravel. To log only error 500 responses for failed mail delivery, you can customize the mail notification and implement logging logic in the failed method of the notification class.

```
public function failed($notifiable, $exception)
{
    // Log only if the response status code is 500 (internal server error)
    if ($exception->response->status() === 500) {
        Log::error('Failed to send mail: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```